Can I use pug template with angular builder esbuild?
In angular 17, I am using "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser".
Now I want to use esbuild buider. But my project currently use pug template alter for html.
Can I config pug compiler like plugin of esbuild?
Use pug template in angular 17 use esbuild builder

There are ongoing related discussions. You can follow the progress at:

ngx-pug-builders #12
angular-cli #28600


The default builder doesn't support PUG but, the same team also released the @angular-builders/custom-esbuild builder.

Can you help me the way to apply pug plugin to use custom-esbuild builder? Pls help me!
